# $\gcd(198,288,512)=198x+288y+512z$; $x,y,z\in\Bbb Z$; solve for $x,y,z$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I stuck this problem I can solve for 2 variable, but 3 variable or more I have no idea about it. Anyone can give me a hint?

Comment: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100923051301AA3a69E  and https://issuu.com/tsangkinfun/docs/_david_m._burton__elementary_number/45

Comment: Thank you for link . It's solve my problem completely ^ ^

Comment: What do you mean satisfies?  If I take $x=y=z=1$ I get $998$.  Does $998$ satisfy your expression?

Comment: It ask for linear combination of gcd.I forgot to put gcd in problem

Comment: Isn’t the gcd equal to $2$? That’s already the gcd of $198$ and $512$, so you can ignore the $288$ part.

Comment: I notice none of the existing answers give a way to find the *general* solution, only a way to find some specific solution.  I wonder if it would be worthwhile for me to write up an example showing how to find the general solution, for example using a Smith normal form expression of $\begin{bmatrix} 198 & 288 & 512 \end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, obviously

$$\begin{align}
1 &= \frac{198x + 288y + 512z}{\gcd(198, 288, 512)}\\
\gcd(198, 288, 512)&=\gcd(2\cdot99, 2\cdot144, 2^9) = 2\\
1 &= 99x + 144y + 256z
\end{align}$$

$\gcd(99,144)=9$ so there are $a,b$ where $9 = a99 + b144$
$\gcd(144, 256) = 16$ so there are $c,d$ where $16 = c144 + d256$
$\gcd(9,16) = 1$ so there are $e,f$ where $1 = e9 + 16f$

So we want $$\begin{align}
1&=e(a99 + b144) + f(c144 + d256)\\&= 99ae + 144(be+fc)+ 256df\\
&x = ae;\quad y = be+fc;\quad z = df\\
1 &= 9e + 16f\end{align}$$

Use Euclid's algorithm: $$\begin{align}
16 &= 9 + 7;& 7&=16-9\\
9&=7+2;& 2&=9-7\\
7 &= 3(2) + 1;& 1&= 7-3*2\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}&=(16-9) - 3(9-7) = (16-9)-3(9 - (16-9))\\
&= 4\cdot16 - 7\cdot9\end{align}$$

So $$e = -7;\quad f= 4\\
x = -7a;\quad y = -7b+4c;\quad z = 4d$$

$$\begin{align}
16 &= c144 + d256\\
1 &= 9c + 16d\\
16 &= 9 + 7;\quad 7 = 16 - 9\\
9 &= 7+2;\quad 2 = 9-7\\
7 &= 3(2) + 1;\quad 1 = 7-3(2)= (16-9)-3(9-7)\\
&=16 - 4\cdot9 + 3(16-9)\\
&=4\cdot16 - 7\cdot9
\end{align}$$

So $$c= -7;\quad d=4\\
x = -7a;\quad y = -7b-28;\quad z = 16$$

And finally $$\begin{align}
9 &= 99a + 144b\\
1 &= 11a + 16b\\
16 &= 11 + 5\\
11 &= 2\cdot5 + 1\\
1 &= 11- 2(5)=11-2(16-11) = 3\cdot11 - 2\cdot16
\end{align}$$

So $$a=3;\quad b=-2\\
x = -21;\quad y = -14;\quad z = 16$$

And $$2 = 198(-21) + 288(-14) + 16(512)$$

Comment: It's easier using the extended Euclidean algorithm - e.g. see my answer.

Comment: d'oh.  Should have thought of that. Truth is I've always had trouble doing the euclidean algorithm without mistakes.  It's easier and shorter with more variables I guess.

Comment: One of the main reasons for presenting the extending Euclidean algorithm that way is that it completely avoids the tedious and highly error-prone final back-substitution phase.

Comment: Yeah,  I really should have seen that.  It's the same thing but tighter so there are fewer steps.  Each step slightly harder but a *lot* more consise and less error prone.

Answer (score 1):

Cancelling $2$ it suffices to solve $\,\gcd(256,144,99) = 256 z + 144 y + 99 x,\,$ which is straightforward using a version of the extended Euclidean algorithm [described here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242), namely

$$\rm\begin{eqnarray}(1)\quad 256\!\ &=&\ \  1&\cdot& 256\ +\ \  0 &\cdot& 144\ +\ 0 &\cdot& 99 \\ 
(2)\quad 144 \ &=&\ \  0 &\cdot& 256 \ +\ \ 1 &\cdot& 144\ +\  0&\cdot& 99\\
          (3)\ \,\quad  99 \ &=&\ \  0 &\cdot& 256 \ +\ \ 0&\cdot& 144\ +\  1&\cdot& 99\\
2(2)-(1)\,\rightarrow\, (4)\ \ \quad 32 &=& {-}1&\cdot&256\ +\ \ 2&\cdot&144\ +\ 0&\cdot& 99\\
(3)\!\!-3(4)\,\rightarrow\, (5)\ \ \ \ \quad3 &=&\ \ 3&\cdot&256\ \  -\ 6&\cdot&144\ +\ 1&\cdot&99\\
11(5)-(4)\,\rightarrow\,(6)\ \ \ \ \quad 1 &\,=\,& 34&\cdot&256 \,-68&\cdot&144+11&\cdot&99
\end{eqnarray}\qquad$$

[See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2338268/242) for another worked example, and [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3327153/242) for an explicit formula for the general trivariate linear Diophantine equation (in terms of solutions of associated bivariate equations).

Comment: As Lubin noted, clearly $\, 256 = 2^8$ is copime to $99$ so we can reduce to two variables writing $\,1 = 256z + 99x\,$ with $\,y=0.\,$ But I thought it would be more instructive to do a trivariate example, given the OP's remarks.

Comment: [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2338268/242) for another worked example.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using different combinations.There are four possible cases.

$$\begin{cases}x=y&(1)\\y=z&(2)\\x=z&(3)\\x\neq y\neq z&(4)\end{cases}$$

Solutions possible in case $(1)$:

$$\begin{align}
198x+288y+512z&=2&[x=y]\\
486x+512z&=2\\
512-486&=26\\
(26*a)-2&\neq512b\\
(26*c)-2&\neq486d\\
\end{align}$$

So case $(1)$ has no solutions. Similarly for case $(3)$ no solution exists.

For case $(2)$:

$$800z+198x=2$$

It means either $x$ or $z$ should be negative.

Since the last digit of $800z$ is $0$, the last digit of $198x$ must be $8$.
It means we can take $x$ as a digit which ends with 1.

Since the last second digit of $800z$ is $0$ the last second digit in $198x$ must be $9$. To get a value $9$ in $10$s place we need to consider digit $0$ in $10$s place for $x$.

$$\frac{800}{198}\approx4\implies z\approx4x$$

By considering all, we get solutions as

$$\begin{align}
x_1&=101,&z_1&=25\\
x_2&=501,&z_2&=124\\
&\vdots\\
x_n&=400+x_n-1,&z_n&=z_n-1 +4 (z_1) -1,&y_n&=z_n
\end{align}$$

It means infinite solutions exist as according to case $(3)$.
Solution to case four is already given by fleablood.