# Finding specific solution for a Diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

The equation given $18 = 3x + 2y + 1/2z$ where $x, y, z$ are positive integers and $20 = x+y+z$.

Now, not really knowing what to do, I multiplied through by $2$ to make it a linear Diophantine equation with three unknowns, this gives $36 = 6x + 4y + z$. Solving this using [a technique I found on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514105/how-do-i-solve-a-linear-diophantine-equation-with-three-unknowns) I was able to obtain a solution to the original equation: $18 = 3(36) + 2(-36) + (-36)1/2$.

As I said, that is a solution, but not within the constraints I want. $x, y, z$ are not all positive integers and they also don't sum up to $20$. (The correct solution is $x = 2$ and $y = 2$ and $z = 16$, found with [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=positive%20integer%20solutions%20%2018%20%3D%203x%20%2B%202y%20%2B%20%281%2F2%29z%20for%20x%2By%2Bz%3D20).)

Now, assuming I know how to solve linear Diophantine equations with three unknowns, how would I take the constraint into account that $x,y,z$ need to sum up to a certain positive integer? What would be the approach here to find the correct solution?

Comment: Solving both, you get $5x + 3y = 16$ which may make it easier to see only one possible values for $x, y$ and then plug in $x + y + z = 20$ to find $z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{cases}
6 x+4 y+z=36\\
x+y+z=20\\
\end{cases}
$$
Subtract the two equations
$$5x+3y=16\tag{1}$$
which is satified for positive integers only by $x=2,y=2$.

substitute in the second equation $z=20-x-y$ and get $z=16$, so the unique solution is $x=2,y=2,z=16$.